# Jasmine cannot find Node types

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I have started redoing some tests and it turns out that Jasmine does not find nodejs namespace anymore.
When I try to run 'ng test' I get errors like 'Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.' and 'Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'. It is stuff that I use in my code. When I run 'ng serve' I don't have any problems.

I have added the following to my tsconfig.app.json :

```
"types": ["node"],
"typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
]
```

(I have also tried with "../node_modules/@types")

and the following to the tsconfig.base.json:

```
"types": ["node"]
```

Do you have any idea what it might be? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try npm i --save-dev @types/node ?? as suggested message

Comment: Try doing the same thing that you did in `tsconfig.app.json` in `tsconfig.spec.json`.

Comment: @AliF50 That solved it. Thanks a lot! :))

Of course I have tried the suggested message.